# Fazer insert com select

Tags: mysql, pdo

Tenho uma tabela chamada rótulo, com nomeTag varchar e quant int 11.

Quando eu inserir na tabela rótulo, eu tenho que aumentar a **quantidade total registrada no banco +1**. Mas eu não sei como fazer isso sem ter que fazer outra query a mais e então adicionar através de php. **Tem como fazer isso, sem todo o processo de outra query com PHP?**

```
$querysql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO rótulo(nomeTag, quant) VALUES(?,?)");
$querysql->bindValue(1, $nomeTag);
$querysql->bindValue(2, "SELECT quant+1 FROM rótulo"); // nessa linha qe eu ñ sei
$querysql->execute();
```

Tem como fazer algo assim? Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: é necessário primeiro selecionar a tabela e depois fazer insert

Comment: Não existe outra maneira? Parecida com o exemplo que perguntei?

Comment: estou falando que eu acho mais viável , porém você pode esperar alguém mais experiente, mas eu particularmente nunca utilizei e nem vi exemplo assim

Comment: creio que quando você insere o registro você já tem um registro a mais, ou seja, +1, no seu banco de dados. veja se seu banco de dados tem id <auto increment>

Comment: `insert select` tem outra sintaxe.

Comment: É para fazer um contador de quantos posts tem com determinado rótulo, e num pode ser auto-increment

Comment: Precisa mesmo guardar essa quantidade? não é melhor fazer um `count()` quando recuperar essas informações? essa situação parece a mesma de gravar idade como um `int` aí todo ano vc incrementa :)

Comment: Esse nameTag será repetido mesmo?

Comment: Eu usaria um TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php

Comment: Não faz sentido o que você está tentando fazer, ou não entendi a sua pergunta, pois é só você criar um campo com chave primaria e auto_increment que fará isso pra você automaticamente, Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html